# how to find parent TabPage of widget in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, parent-child, qtabwidget

I found code for finding child widget <Top-widget.findChildren(widget-type)>, but I couldn't able to find command for getting parent widget.

I created QTabWidget with multiple tabs . in each tabs I have some widgets.
I want to highlight tab page of given widget element.

I created one code to achieve this. and it is working. but I feels this is not straight forward. can you suggest better solution to achieve the same?

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def color_parent_tab(widget,Tab):
    tabs={Tab.widget(i):i for i in range(Tab.count())}
    while widget!=None:
        try:
            if widget in tabs:
                Tab.tabBar().setTabTextColor(tabs[widget], QColor('red'))
            widget=widget.parent()
        except Exception as e:print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window=QTabWidget()

    w=QWidget()
    VL=QVBoxLayout(w)
    window.addTab(w,'tab1')

    L=QLabel('Label1')
    VL.addWidget(L)

    L2=QLabel('Label2')
    VL.addWidget(L2)

    w=QWidget()
    VL=QVBoxLayout(w)
    window.addTab(w,'tab2')

    L3=QLabel('Label1')
    VL.addWidget(L3)

    L4=QLineEdit()
    VL.addWidget(L4)

    color_parent_tab(L3,window)

    window.showMaximized()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isAncestorOf`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#isAncestorOf), which returns `True` if the widget in the argument is a child (or grandchild, at any level):

```
def color_parent_tab(widget, Tab):
    for i in range(Tab.count()):
        if Tab.widget(i).isAncestorOf(widget):
            Tab.tabBar().setTabTextColor(i, QColor('red'))
            return
```